# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, json, swift, data-extraction

I want to access some data of my Json that is inside another json

here is my code:

```
let extraData = userInfo["extraData"] as! [String : Any]
print(extraData["message_id"])
```

but I get below error while running:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x264300f90) to 'NSDictionary' (0x264301bc0)
```

here is my Json:

> [AnyHashable("largeIcon"): http://test.png, AnyHashable("notifyType"): notifyData, AnyHashable("ledColor"): #f39c12, AnyHashable("extraData"): {"is_background":0,"message_id":"1156","deep_link":{"action_type":"U","url":"teknik://teknik"}}, AnyHashable("message"): test, AnyHashable("id"): 50368138, AnyHashable("vibrate"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1544436390847%bebba17fbebba17f, AnyHashable("autoRun"): false, AnyHashable("action"): {"type":"A","url":"Activity.MessageActivityJava"}, AnyHashable("sound"): 3, AnyHashable("title"): newtest, AnyHashable("aps"): {
>       "content-available" = 1;
>   }]

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
do { 
  let dd =  userInfo["extraData"] as! String  
  let con = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dd.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
  print(con["message_id"]) 
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

as `extraData` value is a json string not a direct dictionary

Comment: That's saves the day "as extraData value is a json string not a direct dictionary". Thanks @Sh_Khan